# How to set default values of fields to empty instead of null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4 and building API for Android and Iphone. I have set default value to null in phpmyadmin but my mobile developers do not want null values in response. There are many APIs so I am looking for short and perfect method.

1. I tried to find something in Laravel model that can help me. I tried following code as well.
2. Also tried setting default value in phpmyadmin but it does not accepts default: "As defined" is equal to empty value.
3. Third option could be to loop through laravel Model response and convert null to empty or zero based on data type but that will increase processing time and will increase our most of work as well.

   ```
    public static function boot() { parent::boot();
     self::creating(function ($my_model) {
       $my_model->some_prop = $my_model->some_prop >= 42 ? $my_model->some_prop: defaultValue();  
       });}
   ```

Is there something in Laravel in Model section or somewhere else where I can set default value to empty fields when field does contain any value or is there any other solution or suggestion means how I can handle this problem?

Comment: "my mobile developers do not want null values in response". If something's null, it's null. For example, an empty string is not the same as null. An empty string could be a valid value for a field, where null would not be (implying the field was never even considered or initialised). They're different for a reason. I think your mobile developers are not being sensible.

Comment: Agreed. A null value is a value in the same sense an empty string or 0 is. It represents a possibility that '' or 0 cannot. Tell your mobile "developers" to pick up a programming 101 book.

Comment: Can you add your controller, where you're storing data.

Comment: @GauravDave Sorry I did not understand. "Storing data" means, I did not understand which code I need to paste here so kindly simplify